# How to Show spinner for every HTTP requests in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

i am new to angular 5 . How to code a common function to show spinner for every HTTP request in angular 5.Please help me to implement this.

Comment: You could use PaceJs, it's not angular specific,but it does this out of the box

Comment: I think it is not good idea to show single spinner for ANY xhr request. You will probably need more details in the future

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385627/how-to-implement-a-loading-spinner-with-a-angular-5-ng-template

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use Angular [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to show a spinner for all your requests, Here's a good [medium article on how to implement an http interceptor](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

Also, you will have to create a spinner service/module and inject it in your http interceptor. Finally, in your intercept method you can use the `finally`  rxJs method to stop your spinner. Here's a simple implementation:

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.spinnerService.start();
    return next.handle(req).finally(res => this.spinnerService.stop() );
}
```

Enjoy!

Bonus: Here's a [spinner service implementation example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323108/angular-4-show-a-loading-gif-for-each-http-request)

Comment: Probably dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385369/angular-show-spinner-for-every-http-request-with-very-less-code-changes

Answer (score 4):

**Source [Link](http://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-8-7-show-global-progress-bar-loader-on-http-calls-in-3-steps-using-angular-interceptors-in-angular-4-3/)**

**Create a service**

```
//loader.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoaderService {

  public isLoading = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  constructor() { }
}
```

**Create Loader Interceptor**

```
    // loader.interceptors.ts
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {
        HttpErrorResponse,
        HttpResponse,
        HttpRequest,
        HttpHandler,
        HttpEvent,
        HttpInterceptor
    } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { LoaderService } from './loader.service';

    @Injectable()
    export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        private requests: HttpRequest<any>[] = [];

        constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

        removeRequest(req: HttpRequest<any>) {
            const i = this.requests.indexOf(req);
            if (i >= 0) {
                this.requests.splice(i, 1);
            }
            this.loaderService.isLoading.next(this.requests.length > 0);
        }

        intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

            this.requests.push(req);
            console.log("No of requests--->" + this.requests.length);
            this.loaderService.isLoading.next(true);
            return Observable.create(observer => {
                const subscription = next.handle(req)
                    .subscribe(
                        event => {
                            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                                this.removeRequest(req);
                                observer.next(event);
                            }
                        },
                        err => {
                            alert('error returned');
                            this.removeRequest(req);
                            observer.error(err);
                        },
                        () => {
                            this.removeRequest(req);
                            observer.complete();
                        });
                // remove request from queue when cancelled
                return () => {
                    this.removeRequest(req);
                    subscription.unsubscribe();
                };
            });
        }
    }
```

Now create a loader component then add in the app component

```
  //loader.interceptor.ts
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { LoaderService } from '../loader.service';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-loading',
    templateUrl: './loading.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./loading.component.css']
  })
  export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {

    loading: boolean;
    constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) {
      this.loaderService.isLoading.subscribe((v) => {
        console.log(v);
        this.loading = v;
      });
    }
    ngOnInit() {
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The complete guide is [here](https://firstclassjs.com/display-a-loader-on-every-http-request-using-interceptor-in-angular-7/) with a material `mat-progress-spinner` usage. Very cool!

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with HttpClient or HTTP Requests. It is a question of how to handle asynchronous calls in general (HTTP or not).

You should have

```
<div class="spinner" *ngIf="loading"; else showWhenLoaded"><div>
<ng-template #showWhenLoaded>
    <div>Your Content</div>
</ng-template>
```

and in the ts-file:

```
loading: boolean = true;

methodToTriggerRequest() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.http.get(...).subscribe(response => {
        if (resposnseNotAnError(response)) {this.loading = false}
    })
}
```

Comment: In this way how many loaders are you going to introduce to the application?

Comment: one for each item that needs to be fetched individually. You don't need to block the entire app with a loader if you fetch dynamic data that is used only in one part of the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service and then publish events to it while in the root level of the application subscribed to it. Let me explain.

**broadcast.service.ts** (this is your service)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

/**
 * This class acting as event service bus for the entire app.
 * No Need to register the class as this registered in the root level.
 * Can just inject to componets.
 */
@Injectable()
export class BroadcastService {

    private _handler: Subject<Message> = new Subject<Message>();

    broadcast(type: string, payload: any = null) {
        this._handler.next({ type, payload });
    }

    subscribe(type: string, callback: (payload: any) => void): Subscription {
        return this._handler
            .filter(message => message.type === type)
            .map(message => message.payload)
            .subscribe(callback);
    }
}

interface Message {
    type: string;
    payload: any;
}
```

Then in you can publish and subscribe to events like this:

your service level:

```
this.broadcastService.broadcast('PROGRESS_START');
```

In your app component level:

```
this.broadcastService.subscribe('PROGRESS_START', ()=>{
  //hit when you start http call
  this.myLoader = true;
});
```

finally in app.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="myLoader">
 <!--YOUR LOADER SHOULD GO HERE-->
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is very generic loosely coupled way to implement any loader you want.

Comment: He could also implement NGRX, but this is not what he asked

Comment: He asked about "common function to show spinner for every HTTP request". So in this way he can just publish progress start event from anywhere in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have written some steps to create your own custom progressbar.

1. Create a component

   import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
   @Component({
       selector: 'app-sw-progressbar',
       template: `<div *ngIf="loading">
       <mat-progress-bar style="position:absolute; left:15px; width: calc(100% - 
   30px); height:5px;"
            color="primary"
            mode="indeterminate">
        </mat-progress-bar>
        </div>`,
   })
   export class SWProgresbarComponent {
       @Input() loading = false;
       constructor() { }
   }

2 Import component in module:-

```
import { SWProgresbarComponent } from '../sw-progressbar.component';
@NgModule({
declarations: [SWProgresbarComponent],
imports: [
CommonModule,
MaterialModule,
RouterModule
],
exports: [SWProgresbarComponent,
RouterModule
]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

3. How to use it?

   Here **loading would be true** in the component where you want to show. Add this 
   below code in the component where you want to show the loader.

   `<app-sw-progressbar [loading]="loading"></app-sw-progressbar>`

   For spinner replace mat-progress-bar by mat-progress-spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Create interceptor service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';

@Injectable()
export class SpinnerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this.spinner.show();
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            finalize(() => this.spinner.hide())
        );
    }
}
```

Provide this service in app module

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
                 
        ....
             
@NgModule({       
    providers: [
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: SpinnerInterceptor, multi: true }               
    ]
})
```

Last in app.component inside the router-outlet add your spinner tags

```
 <router-outlet>
    <ngx-spinner bdColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)"
                 size="medium"
                 color="#fff"
                 type="timer">
        <p style="color: #fff"> Loading... </p>
    </ngx-spinner>
</router-outlet>
```

As you can see I am using NgxSpinner but this should make no difference if you're using custom spinner, you just need to create service to show and hide the spinner and inject this service in the spinner interceptor.

Answer (score -1):

In Angular's interceptor I have used "do" operator.

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    // handler for both success and fail response
    const onReqFinish = (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event.type === 4) {
        this.onXhrFinish();
      }
    };

    this.onXhrStart();

    return next.handle(req)
     .do(
       onReqFinish,
       onReqFinish
     );
}
```

onXhrStart function shows a loader and onXhrFinish hides it.

Entire, working source code and demo are [here](https://github.com/salev/loading-indicator)