# How to display a graphic component with an interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular-http-interceptors

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6.
I created an **interceptor service** (using the interface `HttpInterceptor`) which intercepts some types of HTTP calls.
The class works perfectly (I can intercept all the HTTP calls that I want).
In this application there are several graphic components. What is the way to show a graphic component (for example a spinner or a modal window) using code written in the interceptor?

An example:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler ) {

        let updateReq;

        updateReq = req.clone({
            setParams: {
                responseType: 'no-type'
            }
        }
        );

        console.log(updateReq);

        return next.handle(updateReq).pipe(tap(
            event => console.log(event),
            err => console.log(err)
        ));
    }

}
```

For example I would like to test if `req` has some properties, 
then I make a graphic component appear. How do I do this throughout my application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Show spinner for every HTTP requests in angular 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100380/how-to-show-spinner-for-every-http-requests-in-angular-5)

Answer (score 0):

1. create a spinner-component with a flag that shows / hide the spinner
2. create a new service "spinnerservice" wich toggles a flag and emit an event if the spinner is toggled.
3. inject you service in your spinner-component and your intercepter
4. call the "spinnerservice" from the intercepter
5. listen for the event from you service in your spinnercomponent and adjust your spinner state.

Comment: This should be a comment