# How to create a spinner in angular

Tags: angular

I have a requirement How to create a spinner common component with a spinner service(costume service) file for angular 5. that once I click on button and drop down also , spinner should display for few seconds in angular 5 and how to subscribe a method(integrate) , Please share your suggestions(we no need to use any angular plugins)  .Please explain step by step
Thanks in advice

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? I'd be helpful if you include a code example. Also, this might be helpful [How to implement a loading spinner with a Angular (5) ng-template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385627/how-to-implement-a-loading-spinner-with-a-angular-5-ng-template)

Comment: There is an excellent third party library that does that. https://github.com/amitmahida92/ng4-loading-spinner.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of an easy and ready made solution. Download font awesome CSS icon pack from here:

https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started

Then include the 'font-awesome.min.css' file from the css folder within the head tags of your "index.html":

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css"/>
```

Create a spinner component that you can resize and reuse everywhere:

spinner.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component
({
    selector    :  'spinner',
    templateUrl :  './spinner.component.html'
})

export class spinnerComponent 
{
    @Input () spinnerSize; 
}
```

spinner.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf = "spinnerSize == 1">
   <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-1x"></i>
</div>

<div *ngIf = "spinnerSize == 2">
   <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x"></i>
</div>

<div *ngIf = "spinnerSize == 3">
   <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x"></i>
</div>
```

In any template where you would wish to use the spinner just include the following:

```
<spinner [spinnerSize] = 1 ></spinner>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change _loaderShow true false where you want to show or hide loader

**in html file**

```
<div class="loading" *ngIf="_loaderShow">Loading</div>
```

in component file

```
_loaderShow = true;
```

**Css**

```
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  overflow: show;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* Transparent Overlay */
.loading:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

/* :not(:required) hides these rules from IE9 and below */
.loading:not(:required) {
  /* hide "loading..." text */
  font: 0/0 a;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.loading:not(:required):after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  -webkit-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -ms-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
}
```