# How to create a year spinner in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm new to Angular. I'm working on an `Angular 6` project with a team. But there is a major restriction that I'm not allowed to use any 3rd party library. Not even `bootstrap`, `font-awesome` or `primeng`. A `time-selection` widget with `month-range-picker` was required, so I created a custom component from the scratch and it looks good. See:

[image]

The entire time selector widget i created from the scratch and on the right hand side there's a month only range picker that I'm talking about. I've achieved this much so far without outsourcing any framework or library but now I've a blocker. Look at the `year spinner`. It looks pathetic. I want exactly like this. For e.g:

[image]

The one that i've circled red. With left right navigator. Most of the solutions are either using `jquery` or some external `libraries`. Please help me achieve this with pure HTML, CSS and Angular thing.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799675/how-to-create-a-spinner-in-angular) and many other solutions but as I said, they are using jquery mostly. I've created a minimal [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kdhmtw) also. Please help me.

Comment: why not just use angular materials date picker? why reinvent the wheel here? material is basically a part of the framework at this point

Comment: But we dont want to show the dates. We want only the months. Primeng has got a month only picker but that is only aviable after version 6 and for that i'll have to upgrade the package which we should not.

Comment: And lso i've to style it according to the standards of my organization.

Comment: 1. material date picker can be put into a month view and locked that way 2. it can be styled however you want it. both of those tasks will take a fraction of the time to code your own custom datepicker. this is where being an engineer is preferable to being a programmer. date pickers are a solved problem

Comment: Ok @bryan60, thanks for the suggestion. I'll surely look into material.

Comment: @bryan60. My project is in Angular 6.1.10 and material is not a part of it. Again, I've to install something from the outside. And I can't do that. I just talked to my team.

Comment: Material is Made and maintained by the same team as angular core specifically and exclusively for use in angular apps, so it’s not third party if this is an angular app. But If your company isn’t willing to use third party components they’ll have to hire developers who can reinvent the wheel and pay them to do so.

Comment: Thanks @bryan60. I appreciate your help. But the problem is that, this project we've taken from some other team. It contains some legacy code, some artifacts and repositories to which we don't have access. Anyway, I'll bring this up in the next meeting and raise this as a concern. I'll park this issue till next meeting. Thank you once again. :-)

Comment: @bryan60 just for using month-picker, he needs to install complete angular/material. Don't you think this is overhead. I mean if he is already using material then this was a different discussion. Am I making sense?

Comment: @plochie why would installing a dependency be overhead?? The date picker module is well isolated as is all of material. The number of installed packages has no bearing on app size. Only imports do due to the tree shake

Comment: @bryan60, Plochie. Thank you so much guys. I'll talk about this with my team after this sprint. But in the meanwhile I've created my own from the scratch. I'm posting that as an answer. Please review the code and accept (*if you feel like :-) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys, thanks for your precious time on this question. In the meanwhile like the entire widget I created this also from the scratch. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

To keep the project simple and code clean. I created a new custom `year-navigator` component altogether.

Here is the code.

**yearnavigator.component.html**

```
<div class="super-div">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td><i class="iconfont left-arrow" (click)="decrementYear()">&#xf15f;</i></td>
            <td>
                <pt-label class="current-year">{{year}}</pt-label>
            </td>
            <td><i class="iconfont right-arrow" (click)="incrementYear()">&#xf160;</i></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**yearnavigator.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import './yearnavigator.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-yearnavigator',
  templateUrl: './yearnavigator.component.html'
})
export class YearnavigatorComponent {

  dt = new Date( );

  year: number=this.dt.getFullYear();

  constructor() { }

  decrementYear() {
    this.year=(this.year)-1;
    console.log("clicked");
  }

  incrementYear() {
    this.year=(this.year)+1;
    console.log("clicked");
  }
}
```

**yearnavigator.component.css**

```
.iconfont {
    font-family: "dls-images" !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.2px;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.super-div {
    /* background: crimson; */
    width: 327px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.current-year {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #2B86B2;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.left-arrow,
.right-arrow {
    color: #2B86B2;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.left-arrow:hover,
.right-arrow:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**PS:** `iconfont` is from our own library of icons. You can use any other library. It's just an icon thing.

Please feel free to post a better answer. I know i'm a pathetic coder. :-(